# How to access banned websites that cannot be accessed through windows but can be accessed through other OSes?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, vpn, web, blocking

Some websites that are banned in my country cannot be accessed on computer (with windows installed) but if I try them on android phone (using same broadband wifi as PC) they can be accessed. I initially thought it was because of PC but later I found that those websites couldn't be accessed through Ubuntu. However, on Ubuntu I installed QEMU and in it I ran Kolibri OS (a hobby OS written entirely in assembly) and I found that inside QEMU emulator i could access those websites on Kolibiri OS. That makes it clear that the problem is with windows and Ubuntu. Can something be done so that those websites can be accessed on these two OSes without having to use VPN or Onion Routing?

Comment: Just to be clear, is this is a site capture blocker (where you are redirected to a 'this is blocked' site) or a simple HTTP  code (like a 404 not found) or a blank screen response?

Comment: Well it states, "The website cannot be accessed, its IP address not found". Butt the same can be accessed on some other os.

Comment: It Also states "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

Comment: Check DNS settings on your computer. Try replacing the automatically provisioned DNS servers with the Google DNS `8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

I came from an east-Asia country which is famous for its Walls.So I have faced these troubles a lot of times.I think you might be facing two Walls.

1. DNS pollution
2. banned IP

In your case. Kolibri OS maybe set a default DNS like Google or OpenDNS.The other 2 OSs you used maybe ask your ISP for DNS servers.A good news is that your country does not ban these DNS servers.

So we can think, this website is polluted, but not be banned yet.That's my answer to your question.

But there is another question I think you need to ask: Whether your ISP knows that you are reaching a banned site? If you are not using a VPN, the answer is yes. It could be dangerous in some countries. But if you are using a VPN or Onion-Routing, your ISP knows you are using these too. Maybe you need to study a lot first to secure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the simpler cases, the whole network setup makes you use your ISP's DNS, that rejects attempts to resolve the blocked sites. Two solutions:

1. change your network configuration and set the DNS manually to the Google DNS (8.8.8.8) or OpenDNS (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) for addresses).
2. obtain the address once (`nslookup` or `dig` on Linux, forcing one of the DNS servers in the previous solution), and add the address to your `/etc/hosts` file (on Linux) or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (on Windows, from memory). Note that altering `etc/hosts` is also done sometimes by malware, so you may trigger your security software by doing so.